# Keycloak Invalid token issuer

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I have a mobile app(react-native), a resource service(spring boot) and Keycloak Authenticatioin Service(Auth-Service).

Client makes authentication directly with Auth-Service and gets the access token.
When I do a request to the resource service, the resource service checks the access token by asking to the Auth-Service. But token obtained by the client app and iss field is http://10.0.2.2:8060/auth/realms/sau and my resource service at http://localhost:8110.

Keycloak says:  `error="invalid_token", error_description="Invalid token issuer. Expected 'http://localhost:8060/auth/realms/sau', but was 'http://10.0.2.2:8060/auth/realms/sau'"`

**My question is how can I make authentication in resource service behalf my client?**

**Mobile App:**

```
 export const prepareRequestBody = credentials => {
  const params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append('username', credentials.username);
  params.append('password', credentials.password);
  params.append('client_id', "nasilim-mobile-app");
  params.append('grant_type', "password");
  return params;
};

export const login = credentials => {
  const params = prepareRequestBody(credentials);
  return axios.post(LOGIN, params);
};
```

[image]

**Resource-Service:**

**application.yml**

```
keycloak:
  realm: sau
  resource: photo-service
  bearer-only: false
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:8060/auth
  credentials:
     secret: 69a3e80c-8360-42df-bcec-b6575a6949dc
```

[image]

Note: I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51554178/invalid-token-issuer-when-running-keycloak-behind-proxy) question and I have tried to set "X-Forwarded-For" : "http://localhost:8060/" but It didn't work Keycloak returns:
 `{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "HTTPS required"
  }`

Here is a [Sample Access Token](https://jwt.io/#id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJXWHJwMDBJcDJ1RW5ZS2x2LWFfeTgzb29OU3Y1alhuNE91N3lTSzZOVElFIn0.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.2zgtr_o1uuBMjWTDw6xW7LU2Keu3DiPalNt_KCpS_Z1ASUHR8J4q_v-JPKglbSY7Zrn6_a_28AwmuK8BhZ5geh6njCuwBqouQTfXcUPEkl476oHzNmWXSGShA4loieNBA3TIVjVdy1uKThGDCRdi7iF4na4tAchO7j2qrOe3zxPl7OYLJjf0MJRHw3IGzeHLZyOsnY60B-XqIznZ49UmVAgcyszGT_32brdUeFstjQQONY8br-4aJPrAo_FEMtdNhnYFAFOFHhJAtP_IlU07vY3Lc9KoggR9fmaJRb6aYP9qmk4RMwsD0GXCismlzjGf6zQVe-AXKAJXmdpAvxs9qA) that obtained by mobile client.

Comment: I had to use the `keycloak.proxy-url` setting https://christophewillemsen.com/2021/06/08/keycloak-invalid-token-issuer-when-running-locally-with-docker/

Answer (score 14):

The "iss" claim vary in function of the request. The variable [KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/) can change this behavior. So try do as follow in your docker-compose file:

```
KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL: http://10.0.2.2:8060/auth
```

Comment: Latest versions uses `KC_FRONTEND` or `KC_FRONTEND_URL`. Details here: https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure access from your Spring Boot app to the Auth server in an external fashion, not *localhost*:

```
keycloak:
  realm: sau
  resource: photo-service
  bearer-only: false
  auth-server-url: http://10.0.2.2:8060/auth
  credentials:
     secret: 69a3e80c-8360-42df-bcec-b6575a6949dc
```

This way the token issuers will match. This will probably require either to disable SSL requirement for external request in keycloak or to configure proper SSL communication. If this is meant for production, do the right way.

**See also:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42504805/1199132

Answer (score 2):

What if you can not access the auth server using the external address? This will not work. Check https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-6984
One workaround is to set the **reaml public key**. But it's not recommended as the adapter will not check for new key  if the key is rotated.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is because inside "container" there is different ip(host).
Keycloak has property `hostname-url`. You should inform keycloak about your frontend(hosts). You can do that during starting new instance of keycloak. Command to start your keycloak is `start-dev --hostname-url=url-to-your-frontend`
you can provide the hostname of frontend, so the command will be look like this:

`start-dev --hostname-url=http://10.0.2.2:8060`

This solution is working for Keycloak version 19 and up

Answer (score 1):

**Fast answer**: use [KC_HOSTNAME_URL](https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config?q=front) if uses quay.io/keycloak/keycloak image

**Explanation**:

Using https://jwt.io/ make sure that iss property in the JWT token is the same URL as issuer uri.
For image [quay.io/keycloak/keycloak](https://quay.io/keycloak/keycloak) should be used [KC_HOSTNAME_URL](https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config?q=front) property.

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64771663/9209083) its 'iss' issue. To be specific, this logic is located in `org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils` which is part of `org.springframework:spring-security-oauth2-jose:6.1.2(my version)`

And here is the code: just compare issuer with meta issuer (which we override by using KC_HOSTNAME_URL property)

```
static void validateIssuer(Map<String, Object> configuration, String issuer) {
        String metadataIssuer = getMetadataIssuer(configuration);
        Assert.state(issuer.equals(metadataIssuer), () -> "The Issuer \"" + metadataIssuer
                + "\" provided in the configuration did not " + "match the requested issuer \"" + issuer + "\"");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `proxy-url` in the adapter configuration to provide an alternative URL.
See [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#:%7E:text=value%20is%20false.-,proxy%2Durl,-The%20URL%20for).

Spring `application.yml`:

```
keycloak:
  authServerUrl: http://10.0.2.2:8060/auth
  proxyUrl: http://localhost:8060/auth
  ...
```

Or `keycloak.json`:

```
{
  "auth-server-url": "http://10.0.2.2:8060/auth",
  "proxy-url": "http://localhost:8060/auth",
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At keycloak go to your realm then to realm settings and place the url you want at frontend url.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error, I have keyclok run inside container and my service on localhost, solved that by open page clients/yourClientName/settings & changed Access Settings (Root,Home,valid redirect, valid post, admin URL) to my service local address:

```
http://localhost:servicePort
```

So if you have service running inside container I think you will have to try change above Access Settings to the new IP Address.
You can get your container ip address by using:

```
docker inspect \ -f "{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}"  container_name_or_id
```